# pandas dataframe with Date index -> insert into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mysql-python

The object `df` is of type pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.

```
In [1]: type(df)
Out[1]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The index of `df` is a DatetimeIndex

```
In [2]: type(df.index)
Out[2]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

And `con` gives a working MySQLdb connection

```
In [3]: type(con)
Out[3]: MySQLdb.connections.Connection
```

I've not been able to get this dataframe entered into a MySQL database correctly, specifically, the date field comes through as null when using the following (as well as some variations on this).

```
df.to_sql( name='existing_table',con=con, if_exists='append', index=True, index_label='date', flavor='mysql', dtype={'date': datetime.date})
```

*What are the steps required to have this dataframe entered correctly into a local MySQL database, with 'date' as a date field in the db?*

Comment: It's a long-shot and that's why I'm writing a comment and not an answer, but does it work if instead of `dtype={'date': datetime.date}` you use `dtype={'date': datetime.datetime}`? If not, does it simply insert `null` to the db or does it throw an error?

Also, by reading `to_sql` documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html , it seems like `dtype` is optional, but if present I believe it should contain all the columns.

Comment: made that change but it still just enters nulls. It doesn't throw an error in either case

Comment: Plain MySQLdb connections are not supported for writing to a database. You have to wrap that connection in a SQLAlchemy engine (pandas uses that for the database flavor specific differences). With a plain DBAPI connection, only sqlite is supported. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql

Comment: Further, what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: You will have to upgrade your pandas version to at least 0.15 to be able to correctly write the dates to a MySQL database. With this older version, you can indeed use a MySQLdb connection, but datetime types were not processed correctly. Newer pandas versions improved the support by using SQLAlchemy (see my previous comment).

Comment: Thanks joris, that has done it. (Also `dtype` field was unnecessary)

Answer (score 1):

To correctly write datetime data to SQL, you need at least pandas 0.15.0.

Starting from pandas 0.14, the sql functions are implemented using SQLAlchemy to deal with the database flavor specific differences. So to use `to_sql`, you need to provide it an [SQLAlchemy engine](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html) instead of a plain MySQLdb connection:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://....')

df.to_sql('existing_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=True, index_label='date')
```

Note: you don't need to provide the flavor keyword anymore.

Plain DBAPI connections are no longer supported for writing data to SQL, except for sqlite.

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql for more details.